# Detox Primitive ReferenceError: Element is not defined

Tags: jestjs, react-native-ios, detox

potentially related issues
[#795](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/795)

Description
I am new to using Detox but it appears to me that primitives are not being properly set as jest globals following the setup and usage guides I could find in the documentation. I get the code in the console ReferenceError: element is not defined. Maybe there is a way to improve the logging to clarify these config errors for good

Repo to reproduce:
https://github.com/Kielan/OnyxWalletReactNative

Detox v8.1.6^
Node v8.9.4,
React Native v0.56.0
Device iphone 7 sim release and debug

Device and verbose Detox logs
ReferenceError: element is not defined

```
  14 | })
  15 | 
> 16 | it(':ios: shows splash screen and then login', async () => {
     |                                                ^
  17 |   await expect(element(by.label('animateLoginLabel'))).toBeVisible()
```

Comment: everybody is getting the same error but so far no solution